# Missing XML attribute - attribute "Version"

Tags: xml, sitemap, google-shopping-api, google-search-console

I got a question about my site's Google Shopping XML... 
on the Search Console, the XML's appearing with an error...

> "Missing XML attribute" / "Attribute: version".

I'd analyze it, and checked the "Version attribute" is already inside the XML file... but, I don't know if this information is correctly programmed... 'cause the error stays.

[image: Search Console]

[image: XML]

Answer (score 0):

The attribute it is looking for is `version`. 
You are supplying `VERSION`.
XML is case sensitive and so is the matching done by XSL templates, XPATH queries and XSD validation.
Even though your XML is well-formed the client parsing/validating the XML is expecting the attribute to be named `version` (all lower case).